# Q function in Baum-Welch algorithm

Tags: maximum-likelihood, hidden-markov-model, expectation-maximization, baum-welch

Assume there's a hidden Markov Model $\lambda=(\pi, \mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B})$, where $\pi$ is an initial distribution, $\mathbf{A}$ is a transition matrix and $\mathbf{B}$ is an emission matrix. Also, there is a reestimated model $\bar \lambda = (\bar \pi,\mathbf{\bar A},  \mathbf{\bar B})$. The idea of obtaining ML estimates via Baum-Welch algorithm lies in maximizing the Q function:
\begin{align}
Q(\lambda, \bar \lambda) = \sum\limits_Q \mathbb{P}(Q \mid O, \lambda)\log \mathbb{P}(O, Q \mid \lambda)
\end{align}
However, I frequently see a differently expressed Q function, namely
\begin{align}
Q(\lambda, \bar \lambda) = \sum\limits_Q \mathbb{P}(Q, O \mid \lambda)\log \mathbb{P}(O, Q \mid \lambda)
\end{align}
Obviously,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(Q \mid O, \lambda) = \dfrac{\mathbb{P}(Q, O \mid \lambda)}{\mathbb{P} (O\mid \lambda)}
\end{align}
So
\begin{align}
Q(\lambda, \bar \lambda) = \sum\limits_Q \mathbb{P}(Q \mid O, \lambda)\log \mathbb{P}(O, Q \mid \lambda) = \dfrac{1}{\mathbb{P}(O \mid \lambda)}\sum\limits_Q \mathbb{P}(Q, O \mid \lambda)\log \mathbb{P}(O, Q \mid \lambda)
\end{align}
My question is: is dropping $\mathbb{P} (O\mid \lambda)$ allowed because of the fact that we are maximizing w.r.t. $\bar \lambda$, thus this term is simply a constant?